# How do I extract a partial string based on another column of strings?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I am transforming output from a scheduling system.  I want to create 2 new columns from one initial column. The first desired column has the first six characters from the initial column. The desired second column should have a combination of blank rows and partial string matches. I am a beginner. Resources welcome where I am making ignorant syntax mistakes.

Initial data file looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `Schedule Title` `Staff or Resource Name`                                
  <chr>            <chr>                                                   
1 Consultation     BIO210 (Bio stat); Carl; LSP143 (computer lab)          
2 Weekly           PHY111; (Physics I); Noah/Prof Stubbin                  
3 Weekly           CHM111 (Gen Chem); Ali/Prof Van Arman                   
4 Workshops        CHM111 Quant Skills Workshop, KAU104                    
5 Workshops        CPS111 Study Jam (Computer Science)                     
6 Workshops        CHM211 Organic Chem Study Tips from Q&SC Tutors, HARWOOD
```

Desired file:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Schedule Title` `Course` `WorkshopName`                            
  <chr>            <chr>  <chr>                                   
1 Consultation     BIO210                                      
2 Weekly           PHY111                                      
3 Weekly           CHM111                                     
4 Workshops        CHM111 Quant Skills Workshop                   
5 Workshops        CPS111 Study Jam                               
6 Workshops        CHM211 Organic Chem Study Tips from Q&SC Tutors
```

I have no problem using `str_sub` to create 'Course'.

However, I have not been able to create 'WorkshopName' successfully.  I have tried a) filtering by 'Type' then extracting characters 8-end.  I have tried b) extracting characters 8-end and then replacing anything after `,` `;` or `\(` with empty text.  Both approaches (even if they worked) are only a partial solution.

```
#1. This works and creates the Course column
QSC$Course <- str_sub(QSC$Staff.or.Resource.Name, start = 1, end = 6)

#2. This does not work.  I was trying to filter by 'Type', then create WorkshopName for only those of Type: Workshop. I would still need to clean up the WorkshopNames to eliminate everything after a , ; or (.
QSC %>%
filter(str_detect(Type, 'Workshops') ) %>%
WorkshopName = str_sub('Staff or Resource Name', start = 8, end = -1)

#3. This also does not work.  I tried to extract characters 8-end, then replace anything after , ; or (.  
#I have not been able to successfully escape the character (. 
#I haven't even gotten to the part where I intended to filter and replace the strings with blanks for all but Type:Workshop.
QSC$WorkshopName <- str_sub(QSC$`Staff or Resource Name`, start = 8, end = -1)
QSC$WorkshopName <- str_split(QSC$WorkshopName,",", 1)
QSC$WorkshopName <- str_split(QSC$WorkshopName,";", 1)
QSC$WorkshopName <- str_split(QSC$WorkshopName,"\(", 1)
```

1. Creates the 'Course' column I desire.
2. results in

   `Error in QSC %>% WorkshopName = str_sub("Staff or Resource Name", start = 8,  : could not find function "%>%<-"`
3. results in

   `Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\("`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QSC %>%
filter(str_detect(Type, 'Workshops') ) %>%
WorkshopName = str_sub('Staff or Resource Name', start = 8, end = -1)
```

This fails because you need to use `mutate` in order to create a new variable with `dyplr` :

```
QSC %>%
filter(str_detect(Type, 'Workshops') ) %>%
mutate(WorkshopName = str_sub('Staff or Resource Name', start = 8, end = -1))
```

Moreover, to achieve what do you want in your comment, you can use `ifelse`

```
QSC %>%
mutate(WorkshopName = if_else(str_detect(Type, 'Workshops'), str_sub('Staff or Resource Name', start = 8, end = -1), NA))
```

Now:

```
QSC$WorkshopName <- str_split(QSC$WorkshopName,"\(", 1)
```

Fails becuuse you need an extra \ to make R interpret ( correctly:

```
QSC$WorkshopName <- str_split(QSC$WorkshopName,"\\(", 1)
```

Finally, the last argument in all three `str_split` being 1... I think it makes no sense.
If you read `?str_split`

> n: number of pieces to return. Default (Inf) uses all possible split
>   positions

So if you put 1, it will return the whole string, you need 2 or more. If what you want is to get the first piece after the split, you need this so you retain the piece before the (first) split and drop what comes after

```
str_split(QSC$WorkshopName, "\\(")[[1]][1]
```

Best

Comment: I appreciate the crisp,  clear answer. *Using mutate gives me a tibble for the subset Types that have Workshops.  How do I merge it back in with the larger data set?  Ultimately I want all other types to be blank or have NA in the WorkshopName column.   *For the str_split, I want to retain the piece before the split and drop what comes after.

Comment: Hi! I modified my answer to try to work as you comment above!

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. When I try the modification, I get: Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: My bad! I forgot to delete the filter thing, it is not need! I think It must work now

Comment: I ended up modifying the mutate command slightly:     QSCtib <- QSCtib %>% mutate(WorkshopName = if_else( str_detect(Type, 'Workshops'), str_sub(`Staff or Resource Name`, start = 8, end = -1),  "NA", missing = "NA"))

Comment: I also ended up modifying the strsplit using sapply because I needed to apply it to the whole column of splits.   QSC$WorkshopName <-sapply(strsplit(QSC$WorkshopName,";"), `[`, 1)